# How do I get the current YouTube player state via a function such as getPlayerState()?

Tags: javascript, api, video, youtube

I am creating a web page with multiple embedded YouTube videos. And I am trying to write code that will stop one video from playing when another video on the page is started.

I have looked over the YouTube API docs and the best method I could find to test for a "playing" state is getPlayerState().

However, when I use **getPlayerState()** as in the code below, I get an "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function" exception. This is probably happening because that method is an event object member. Because I am trying to test a specific player for a "playing" state, no event object is instantiated for that specific player.

My code is below. The function to review is "**stateChanged()**" where I check a specific  player's status. For now I am using a hard-coded iFrame ID. There is a "debugger" statement in there to force a breakpoint.

Please don't judge the code! It's an experimental mash-up of several Stack Overflow examples that I have found. I'll improve it later once the intended functionality is working.

Thanks!
Chris S.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Embedded YouTube</title>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <script>
    $(document).ready( function() {
      //------------------------------------------------
      // Assign a unique id to each iframe ...
      $('iframe[src*="http://www.youtube.com/embed/"]').each( function(i) {
        $(this).attr('id', 'vid' + i);
        console.log( $(this).attr('id') );
      })

      //------------------------------------------------
      // Is another video is already playing? If so stop it
      function stateChanged(event) {
        if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.BUFFERING) {
          debugger; 
          var player = new YT.Player('vid0');
          var sStatus = player.getPlayerState();
          // The error occurs here...
          if (sStatus == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING)
            player.stopVideo();
        }
      };

      //------------------------------------------------
      // Add function to execute when the API is ready ...
      YT_ready( function() {
        $('iframe[src*="http://www.youtube.com/embed/"]').each( function(i) {
          var frameID = getFrameID( $(this).attr('id') );
          if (frameID) { //If the frame exists
            player = new YT.Player(frameID, {
              events: { "onStateChange" : stateChanged }
            });
          }
        })
      });

    });


    //------------------------------------------------
    // Load YouTube IFrame API
    //------------------------------------------------
    (function() { // Closure, to not leak to the scope
      var s = document.createElement("script");
      s.src = (location.protocol == 'https:' ? 'https' : 'http') + "://www.youtube.com/player_api";
      var before = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
      before.parentNode.insertBefore(s, before);
    })();

    //------------------------------------------------
    //Define a player object, to enable later function calls, without
    // having to create a new class instance again.
    var player; 

    //------------------------------------------------
    // This function will be called when the API is fully loaded
    function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {
      YT_ready(true);
    }

    //------------------------------------------------
    function getFrameID(id){
      var elem = document.getElementById(id);

      if (elem) {
          if(/^iframe$/i.test(elem.tagName)) 
            return id; //Frame, OK

          // else: Look for frame
          var elems = elem.getElementsByTagName("iframe");
          if (!elems.length) 
            return null; //No iframe found, FAILURE

          for (var i=0; i<elems.length; i++) {
             if (/^https?:\/\/(?:www\.)?youtube(?:-nocookie)?\.com(\/|$)/i.test(elems[i].src)) break;
          }

          elem = elems[i]; //The only, or the best iFrame
          if (elem.id) 
            return elem.id; //Existing ID, return it

          // else: Create a new ID
          do { //Keep postfixing `-frame` until the ID is unique
              id += "-frame";
          } while (document.getElementById(id));

          elem.id = id;
          return id;
      }
      // If no element, return null.
      return null;
    }

    //------------------------------------------------
    // Define YT_ready function.
    //------------------------------------------------
    var YT_ready = (function() {
        var onReady_funcs = [], api_isReady = false;
        /* @param func function     Function to execute on ready
         * @param func Boolean      If true, all qeued functions are executed
         * @param b_before Boolean  If true, the func will added to the first
                                     position in the queue*/
        return function(func, b_before) {
            if (func === true) {
                api_isReady = true;
                while (onReady_funcs.length) {
                    // Removes the first func from the array, and execute func
                    onReady_funcs.shift()();
                }
            } else if (typeof func == "function") {
                if (api_isReady) func();
                else onReady_funcs[b_before?"unshift":"push"](func); 
            }
        }
    })();
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div style="height:40px">&nbsp;</div>
  <iframe src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/LsqzXbJMj94?rel=0&enablejsapi=1" width="240" height="135" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
  <iframe src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/HuCaWjfWVx0?rel=0&enablejsapi=1" width="240" height="135" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
  <iframe src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/vbbQn_-9nlg?rel=0&enablejsapi=1" width="240" height="135" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
  <iframe src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/-MIaggsdTS0?rel=0&enablejsapi=1" width="240" height="135" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: not the most expert about this, but how about this:
pseudo code:
`a_vid.play { rest.stop; }`
so you don't need to know what other video is playing, just stop them all anyways and then play the one

Comment: I like that idea. I tried something similar with no luck, but I will revisit it. I'll give it a try and report back. Thanks!